# Big query returned "Unexpected. Please try again."

Tags: google-bigquery

In a big query SELECT request from the python api, I get a 500 error that says "Unexpected. Please try again."

I did the same query on the bigquery cloud console and it worked as expected on there.

My job number is job_bKcWPWlivdJMa5ziC0-mRE__EtU.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up your job, you're running `SELECT *` on a table that is produced in a non-standard way (it is an internal google table made available to some outside researchers). This table has some data types that aren't directly supported by bigquery. My recollection is that these tables use packed bytes to represent ip addresses. These get encoded as strings, but BigQuery gets grumpy when those strings aren't able to be encoded as UTF8. One solution is to avoid selecting those fields if you don't need them.

This should be fixed sometime within the next week; we should end up not returning those fields.

Comment: Great, thanks for clearing this up! Is there a way I can check which columns have the unwanted format? Then I can see if I actually need them.